# Buttons with values, How to calculate a total price

Tags: javascript, html

First I'd like to say that i'm a very new beginner when it comes to java script with no other skills involved. I seem to be a little lost in my coding. I have two sets of options with three choices within each. Each choice has its own price. How do I calculate a total price?

#### JavaScript (included in HEAD)

```
var theForm = document.forms["pizzaOrder"];

var pizza_price = new Array();
pizza_price["meatLover"] = 15.50;
pizza_price["veggieLover"] = 12.50;
pizza_price["supreme"] = 20.00;

function getPizzaPrice() {
var pizzaPrice = 0;
var theForm = document.forms["pizzaOrder"]; //You already declared "theForm" at global scope - no need to redeclare it here to hold the same reference -crush
var pizzaType = theForms.elements["pizzaType"]; //Mispelled "theForm" here -crush

    for(var i = 0; i < pizzaType.length; i++) {
        if(pizzaType[i].checked) {
            pizzaPrice = pizza_price[pizzaPrice[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }

    return pizzaPrice;
}

var extra_top = new Array()
extraTop["extraChees"] = 1.00;
extraTop["mushrooms"] = 1.10;
extraTop["anchovies"]-1.25; //Obvious syntax error here -crush

function getToppingPrice() {
    var toppingPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["pizzaOrder"];
    var extraTop = theForm.elements["extraTop"] //You forgot the semi-colon here -crush

    for(var i = 0; i < extraTop.length; i++) {
        if(extraTop[i].checked) {
            toppingPrice = extra_top[extraTop.value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return toppingPrice;
}

function getTotal() //You're missing an opening bracket here -crush
    var pizzaPrice = getPizzaPrice() + getToppingPrice();
    document.getElementbyId('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Total Price for Pizza is $" + pizzaPrice;
//You're missing a closing bracket here -crush
```

#### HTML

```
<body onload="hideTotal">
<h1>Pizza To Go</h1>
<h2>Order Online</h2>
<form action="" id="PizzaOrder" onsubmit="return false;">
    <p>Select Your Pizza!<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="meatLover" onclick="calculateTotal()"/> Meat Lover $12.50<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="veggieLover" onclick="calculateTotal()"/> Veggie Lover $12.50<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="supreme" onclick="calculateTotal()"/> Supreme $12.50<br />
    <p>Add Extra Toppings!<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="extraTop" value="extraCheese" onclick="calculateTotal()"/> Extra Cheese $1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="extraTop" value="mushrooms" onclick="calculateTotal()"/> Mushrooms $1.10<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="extraTop" value="anchovies" onclick="calculateTotal()"/> Anchovies $1.25<br /> 
</form>
</body>
```

I'm currently lost as it just doesnt seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: According to jsLint you should use `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Comment: "doesn't work" .. how descriptive.

Comment: You've got syntax errors littered throughout your code. Read the comments I added to your code above.

Comment: After you add one price you are breaking out of the loop.  Get rid of the break statement.

Comment: Instead of looping through all of the radio elements, you can simply do: `theForm.elements['pizzaType'].value`. Only one `radio` element can be checked at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could stand to be cleaned up quite a bit in general, but your functional issue is that you should be using an object instead of arrays to hold your item prices. Cleanup notwithstanding, try something like this:

```
var pizza_price = {
    "meatLover": 15.50,
    "veggieLover": 12.50,
    "supreme": 20.00
};
var extra_top = {
    "extraChees": 1.00,
    "mushrooms": 1.10,
    "anchovies": -1.25
};

function getPizzaPrice() {
    var pizzaPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["pizzaOrder"];
    var pizzaType = theForms.elements["pizzaType"];
    for(var i = 0; i < pizzaType.length; i++) {
        if(pizzaType[i].checked) {
            pizzaPrice += pizza_price[pizzaPrice[i].value];
        }
    }
    return pizzaPrice;
}

function getToppingPrice() {
    var toppingPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["pizzaOrder"];
    var extraTop = theForm.elements["extraTop"];
    for(var i = 0; i < extraTop.length; i++) {
        if(extraTop[i].checked) {
            toppingPrice += extra_top[extraTop[i].value];
        }
    }
    return toppingPrice;
}

function getTotal() { return getPizzaPrice() + getToppingPrice(); }
```

If you want to create a jsfiddle I'll take a closer look.